# Java Apm agent with multiple tomcats

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-apm

How to configure multiple tomcats running on same machine to Apm server ? With single tomcat I m able to start APMUI.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure we are on the same page here:

1. You have multiple instances of Tomcat running on the same machine.
2. You have configured APM through `CATALINA_OPTS` as defined in the [Elastic APM docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/application-server-setup.html#setup-tomcat).

I guess the simplest setup would be to have a wrapper script to start each Tomcat instance that exports the right `CATALINA_OPTS`. You could share global settings like the APM server address, but could customize the app name, namespaces,...

Comment: Yes I have set up multiple tomcats.

Comment: Catalina opts I have set for both tomcats. javaagent:/apps/elastic-apm-agent-1.2.0.jar -Delastic.apm.service_name=3dspaceCAS -Delastic.apm.application_packages=org.example,org.another.example -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://localhost:8200 I have used same flag for both tomcats setenv.sh

Comment: So what is the problem? You are not receiving the traces? First, make sure your `CATALINA_OPTS` show up in your Tomcat logs (to make sure they are really applied). There is nothing else that should be required to make this work with multiple Tomcat instances IMO.

Comment: In Catalina.out I could see it has set catalina_opts provided. I m using same apm.service_name for both tomcats. How could I differentiate these tomcats on kibana UI?.

Comment: So you are receiving the events for both Tomcats, you just want to make the differentiation between them? If those are different apps, use different `service_name` for them. Otherwise I would use the environment setting for this: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/blob/master/docs/configuration.asciidoc#environment

Comment: I have tried using different service name but no luck.  Is there any limitations on number of Java agents within one machine / cluster? Suppose if I have six tomcats running on application server can I monitor all these using Apm agents?

Comment: I have multiple Java apps running on a single host and the APM agent is working fine. Though I am using different service names since they are not the same app. One thing you could look into what `context.request.url.full` is set to. I assume your services are running on different ports and you will see which one is being reached based on the full URL.